# Scraping Premier League Results

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I want to add competition and country to the output. How can I do it?

My existing code is:

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome()

class GameData:

    def __init__(self):
        self.date = []
        self.time = []
        self.game = []
        self.score = []
        self.home_odds = []
        self.draw_odds = []
        self.away_odds = []


def parse_data(url):
    browser.get(url)
    df = pd.read_html(browser.page_source, header=0)[0]
    game_data = GameData()
    game_date = None
    for row in df.itertuples():
        if not isinstance(row[1], str):
            continue
        elif ':' not in row[1]:
            game_date = row[1].split('-')[0]
            continue
        game_data.date.append(game_date)
        game_data.time.append(row[1])
        game_data.game.append(row[2])
        game_data.score.append(row[3])
        game_data.home_odds.append(row[4])
        game_data.draw_odds.append(row[5])
        game_data.away_odds.append(row[6])

    return game_data


urls = {
"https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/england/premier-league/results/"
}
if __name__ == '__main__':

    results = None

    for url in urls:
        game_data = parse_data(url)
        result = pd.DataFrame(game_data.__dict__)
        if results is None:
            results = result
        else:
            results = results.append(result, ignore_index=True)
```

I want to add competition and country to the output. How can I do it?

XPATH for Country:

```
/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[6]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/h2/span
```

XPATH for Competition:

```
/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[6]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/h1
```

How do I integrate the same to the existing code?

Comment: use xpath with class id or some attribute, not on the way you do it

Comment: @Wonka I am very new to development and I can use some help. How can I approach it? Can you help with the code?

Comment: @pcauthorn can you help? I have extended your code a bit further but my scraping needs this further information.